# How to create Iterables using parentheses in Dart?

Tags: dart

When I use the following code, it prints `(0, 1`) and the runtimeType is an `Iterable`.

```dart
print(Iterable.generate(2, (i) => i));
```

But when I do the reverse, it gives me a compile-time error.

```dart
print((0, 1).runtimeType);
```

So, how can I create `Iterable` using hardcoded value.

PS: I know I can use `List` which itself is an `Iterable` but I wanted to know can this be done using `()`?

Comment: Just use: `Iterable<int> x = [0,1];`

Comment: `(...)` is just printed so it is possible to have a distinction when printing a `List` and a `Iterable`. It is not any indicator of a syntax you can use in Dart.

Comment: @ΟυιλιαμΑρκευα Doing that basically means you're upcasting the `List` to an `Iterable`.

Comment: @julemand101 Thank you. So, how can I create an Iterable then besides using `List`. `Iterable.generate` does the job but what if you only have hard-coded values as I mentioned in the post?

Comment: You can more get more info about Iterables [here](https://dart.dev/codelabs/iterables).

Comment: @iDecode Can you explain in what scenario it is a problem using a `List` constant for your hardcoded `Iterable` values? It is really just the same unless you are using `runtimeType` somewhere in your code which you should never do for other purposes than debugging.

Comment: @julemand101 There's no such issue. I was just exploring out if there's a way to do that. You can write the answer down and I'll be more than happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned value from `toString()` should not be seen as an indicator for what syntax is valid in Dart even if it is valid syntax for some types of objects.

To differentiate between `List`, `Set` and `Iterable`, Dart will use different output format:

- `List` uses `[]`
- `Set` uses `{}`
- `Iterable` uses `()`

As you have observed, there are no syntax in Dart to create an `Iterable` object. The reason for this is (properly) that it does not really make much sense since `List` implements the `Iterable` interface and can therefore always be used as a `Iterable`. So if you have some amount of hard coded data you want to iterate over you should just use a `const List` instead.

Also, `Iterable` does not contain any data itself but is just an indication of the possibility of iterating over some data structure. So even if we could create an `Iterable` object with some hardcoded values, it would need to have a `List` as storage behind the scene.

This is also why you really only have the constructor `Iterable.generate` (besides `Iterable.empty`) since this takes a function which are called for each value there needs to be returned from the `Iterable`. So again, the `Iterable` itself does never ends up containing any data itself.

Comment: Thank you! There's one more thing I wanted to share, a `const` before a `List` isn't needed since a `List` is shared in the memory.

Comment: @iDecode Depends on the context I would say. If you e.g. have the list defined inside a method, the list will be recreated each time this method is called unless it is `const` which will make it immutable and a shared instance. It would really only be shared if the list is defined as a global variable or a static class variable.